# Duplicated contents warning in Google Webmaster Tools even though I use canonical links

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I have some duplicated pages that show the exact same content on different URLS on my website, and I use canonical links to point them all to one of the pages.

So if Page A, B, C, D and E have the same content, the canonical links on pages B,C,D, and E all point to page A, and page A does not have a canonical link.

I see some warnings in *Google Webmaster Tools* -> *Optimization* -> *HTML Improvements*, regarding duplicated descriptions, titles, and more even though I have used the canonical links.

Have I misunderstood how canonical links work? Isn't this their correct usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing a canonical link or Google did not have a chance to see them all. Many errors shown in Google Webmaster Tools are accumulated over time and only get removed after Google had time to see and re-index the page.

From you description it sounds like you are missing the canonical link on one page. TO be safe, all identical pages should have the canonical link and it should point to the same URL.

Keep in mind that canonical is still considered a suggestion by Google and if for some reason there is substantial differences between those pages, Google may still consider them distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd opt to use:

- Page A `<link rel="canonical" href="http://xxx.com/pageA" />`
- Page B `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">`
- Page C `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">`
- Page D `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">`
- Page E `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">`

Edit: Reasoning for this method for people asking about back link flow when using the noindex, follow tag.

Pages that are no index can still achieve a page rank and still pass backlinks by using the noindex, follow you are informing Google to not index your page but follow the links on the page this means that the juice gained on the noindex page is dripped down to the rest of the site. These back links 'can' even show up in Google Web Master tools.

Extremely popular addons such as All in One SEO for WordPress use such method on Tag pages that are in turn duplicate but may obtain backlinks that don't want to be wasted. There are hundreds of reports if not thousands confirmed cases of this working as well as official wording from [John Mueller at Google Webmaster answering hangout questions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB6IJHxhlRQ&feature=player_embedded#!) (Skip to 33:30 and watch for a couple of mins).

Also in terms of the canonical tag its ok to use it on the correct page and not the correct pages... This tag is only to tell Google 'This is the master' if its found on the master then its ok, the benefits of this is in your CMS if that page magically appears on a page it shouldn't for example no-www, or a page=id?42 then it automatically has the "canonical" tag... Again many of the top SEO plugins for various CMS use this to avoid duplicate content - to imply it must be used on all duplicates but not the master is false. Also the likes of big sites such as BBC and so on all use canonical on the master pages as well as the duplicate pages.

Alternatively you could use this since both methods are valid:

- Page A `<link rel="canonical" href="http://xxx.com/pageA" />`
- Page B `<link rel="canonical" href="http://xxx.com/pageA" />`
- Page C `<link rel="canonical" href="http://xxx.com/pageA" />`
- Page D `<link rel="canonical" href="http://xxx.com/pageA" />`
- Page E `<link rel="canonical" href="http://xxx.com/pageA" />`

Ensure that you use the canonical on the master page. As long as you have something like this it doesn't matter what GMT reports.

Comment: Hi DKOATED, pages that are noindex, follow are still crawled and processed - they are just hidden from the search - In the event noindex pages receive PR from backlinks this is then feed down to the rest of the site. I've updated my answer with references and have many more if you would like ;)

Comment: Also if you are going to use terms like 'simply non-sense' then please cite references that contradicts the answer, Simply telling someone its nonsense doesn't help people reading this page and can wrongly give the impression the answer is incorrect when it may be correct.

Comment: "to imply it must be used on all duplicates but not the master is false": wrong. you MUST use it on all duplicates, but MAY use it on the master (has no effect).

Comment: and still, simply setting duplicates on noindex may refrain google from penalized said pages. Setting canonicals instead or preferably canonicals WITH noindex on duplicate pages is better.

Comment: Yes, your not reading though the lines.... By using it on the master then assume that the same page is accessible via no-www, or a pageID rather than the canonical then because the page renders as it normally would it includes the canonical this is why its better to include canonical on the master page incase that page is accessible though another way that your not aware off... Your going of situations where you know the duplicate pages.

Comment: In the first method is it includes in pageA in case the same page is accessible via pageid or any other method that is not desired. So when that page is loaded from the SQL it includes the conical automatically with no further intervention.....

Comment: point taken. that is indeed a scenario probable. care to include that info in the answer? since your favoured solution as is, may lead to false assumptions... friends again? ;)

Comment: Haha, friends again I'll update... in abit and make it clearly what I mean.

Comment: You could even include both noindex, follow and canonical on the same page B C D E. It really doesn't matter, its not duplicate if its NOT in the viewable index so canonical noindex, can be treated the same if used correctly. I know this sounds strange and I'll make the question better later when I've had at least 2 coffees! its 11am here! FAR TO EARLY! lol

Comment: assume 500 strong different source backlinks to Page B. If set to noindex, you are deindexing it. Perhaps Google started favouring Page B instead of Page A for duplicate entries (since it's same domain). Simply setting Page B to noindex without the canonical to Page A would be stupid, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I do agree that the links would be more powerful to the master page but if the pages are no index these backlinks should be an absolute minimal since most of their traffic will be coming from the index paged and this would receive the most backlinks. I think its down to personal situation, If you have 10,000 backlinks and you want those going straight to the canonical then yea, but a new site I wouldn't even bother and ensure that noindex are on the pages that I do not want people finding unless they navigate on the site.

Comment: The more I think about it the more I lean towards canonical now. OMG! more coffee.

Comment: Google has said that a self-referential canonical is OK, but Bing is against it saying that it is equivelant to an infinite redirect.  From http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2011/10/06/managing-redirects-301s-302s-and-canonicals.aspx: "Pointing a rel=canonical at the page it is installed in essentially tells us 'this page is a copy of itself.'"

Comment: BBC and many of the other top sites in the world use it, I personally go off Google since thats where 99% of my traffic comes from.

Comment: To be honest that just sounds like poor software on Bings bot, because thats like saying say you have a navigation menu that links to 3 pages A B and C... let's say you navigate to Page C then on Page C the navigation menu will still have a Link to C... Surely this is a infinite loop, to suggest that canonical is a redirect is silly of microsoft, its a meta tag that contains information whatever they decide to do with it is down to them.